# Inadvertent multiple returns

Tags: go

I'm building an application where I get muslim prayer data from multiple sources.  The first being S3, the second being aladhan (a public api).  I only want to get data from aladhan if it's not available in S3.  If I do have to get the data from the public source then I upload it to my s3.

Here is the code:

This is my interface loop code.  I've put in print statements to show that I'm running into the return statement twice, once with data in my return struct, the second time the struct is nil.

```golang
// prayeriface.go

package prayer

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MonthPrayerIface interface {
    GetMonthPrayer(input *LookupInput) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error)
}

type PreCurrNextMonthPrayer struct {
    custData          *LookupInput
    CurrentMonthData  *PCal
    PreviousMonthData *PCal
    NextMonthData     *PCal

    prayers []MonthPrayerIface
}

func (p *PreCurrNextMonthPrayer) GetMonthPrayers() (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
    var err error
    var monthlyData *PreCurrNextMonthPrayer
    defer func() {
        fmt.Printf("return monthlyData address & value = %p %v\n", monthlyData, monthlyData)
    }()
    for k, data := range p.prayers {
        fmt.Printf("loop = %v, data= %T %v\n", k, monthlyData, monthlyData)
        monthlyData, err = data.GetMonthPrayer(p.custData)
        fmt.Printf("\terr= %v\n", err)
        fmt.Printf("\tmonthlyData= %p %v\n", monthlyData, monthlyData)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("loop-return: err == nil \n")
            return monthlyData, nil
        }

    }

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("post-loop:\n")
        fmt.Printf("\tmonthlyData= %p %v\n", monthlyData, monthlyData)
        return monthlyData, nil
    }

    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to get prayer data from all sources %s", err)
}

func NewMonthPrayer(input *LookupInput, prayers ...MonthPrayerIface) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
    var err error
    t := &PreCurrNextMonthPrayer{
        custData: input,
        prayers:  prayers,
    }
    t, err = t.GetMonthPrayers()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return t, nil
}
```

As you can see, I'm looping over an interface struct method called `GetMonthPrayer`

This is my s3 source

```golang
// s3.go

package prayer

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "io"
    awsservices "prayer-times/src/aws"
)

// S3Store s3 storage object for prayer calendars
type S3Store struct {
    data *PCal
}

// GetMonthPrayer retrieves prayer data from s3, otherwise from aladhan
func (s *S3Store) GetMonthPrayer(input *LookupInput) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
    mPrayer := new(PreCurrNextMonthPrayer)
    fmt.Println("attempting to retrieve prayer data from s3")
    s3Client := awsservices.NewS3Service()
    pMonthInput := &LookupInput{
        Country:  input.Country,
        ZipCode:  input.ZipCode,
        custTime: input.custTime.AddDate(0, -1, 0),
    }
    nMonthInput := &LookupInput{
        Country:  input.Country,
        ZipCode:  input.ZipCode,
        custTime: input.custTime.AddDate(0, 1, 0),
    }

    // s3Pdata retrieves data from S3 and
    s3pData := func(input *LookupInput) (*PCal, error) {
        pCalendar := new(PCal)
        data, err := s3Client.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key: aws.String(
                fmt.Sprintf(
                    "%s/%d/%d/%d",
                    input.Country,
                    input.ZipCode,
                    input.custTime.Year(),
                    input.custTime.Month())),
        })
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        if data == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("error data from s3 is nil")
        }
        defer func() {
            err := data.Body.Close()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("unable to close s3 body: %s", err)
            }
        }()
        s3buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
        if _, err := io.Copy(s3buf, data.Body); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        dataBytes := s3buf.Bytes()

        decoder := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(dataBytes))
        err = decoder.Decode(&pCalendar)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("unable to decode json: %s", err)
        }

        return pCalendar, nil
    }
    aladhanData := new(AladhanStore)
    getAladhanData := func(input *LookupInput) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
        data, err := aladhanData.GetMonthPrayer(input)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return data, nil
    }

    // Get current data from s3, if not s3, then get all three from aladhan
    cMonthS3Data, err := s3pData(input)
    pMonthS3Data, err := s3pData(pMonthInput)
    nMonthS3Data, err := s3pData(nMonthInput)
    if err != nil {
        adata, err := getAladhanData(input)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
            return nil, err
        }
        return adata, nil
    }
    mPrayer.CurrentMonthData = cMonthS3Data

    // Get previous month data from s3, if not s3, then get all three from aladhan
    mPrayer.PreviousMonthData = pMonthS3Data

    // Get next month data from s3, if not s3, then get all three from aladhan
    mPrayer.NextMonthData = nMonthS3Data

    return mPrayer, nil
}
```

Here is my aladhan source

```golang
// aladhan.go

package prayer

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
    "io"
    "log"
    awsservices "prayer-times/src/aws"
    "prayer-times/src/urljsonoutput"
    "prayer-times/src/zipcoordinates"
)

var (
    aladhanURL string = "https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendar?"
)

// PCal contains the prayer times of the month as well as the return code
type PCal struct {
    Code   int    `json:"code"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
    Data   []struct {
        Timings DailyPrayers
    }
}

/*
AladhanData returns the total monthly prayers of given month, coordinates, and zip from aladhan.
https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendar?latitude=51.508515&longitude=-0.1254872&method=1&month=4&year=2017
*/
func AladhanData(input *LookupInput) *PCal {
    coordinates := zipcoordinates.HereCoordinates(&zipcoordinates.GeoLocationInput{
        PostalCode:  input.ZipCode,
        CountryCode: input.Country,
    })
    respStruct := new(PCal)
    _, err := urljsonoutput.GetURLJSON(fmt.Sprintf(
        "%slatitude=%v&longitude=%v&method=%v&month=%v&year=%v",
        aladhanURL,
        coordinates.Items[0].Position.Latitude,
        coordinates.Items[0].Position.Longitude,
        input.Method,
        int(input.custTime.Month()),
        input.custTime.Year()), respStruct)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to pull monthly prayer data %v", err)
    }

    return respStruct
}

// AladhanStore struct to interact with interface for GetMonthPrayer
type AladhanStore struct {
    data *PCal
}

// GetMonthPrayer Pulls prayer data from aladhan
func (a *AladhanStore) GetMonthPrayer(input *LookupInput) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
    mPrayer := new(PreCurrNextMonthPrayer)

    // Return prayer data from aladhan
    custPMonthTime := input.custTime.AddDate(0, -1, 0)

    pMonthLookupInput := new(LookupInput)
    pMonthLookupInput.custTime = custPMonthTime
    pMonthLookupInput.ZipCode = input.ZipCode
    pMonthLookupInput.Country = input.Country

    custNMonthTime := input.custTime.AddDate(0, 1, 0)
    nMonthLookupInput := new(LookupInput)
    nMonthLookupInput.custTime = custNMonthTime
    nMonthLookupInput.ZipCode = input.ZipCode
    nMonthLookupInput.Country = input.Country

    prayerData := AladhanData(input)
    pMonthPData := AladhanData(pMonthLookupInput)
    nMonthPData := AladhanData(nMonthLookupInput)

    // Save prayer data into io.Reader to save to s3
    var Marshal = func(data interface{}) (io.ReadSeeker, error) {
        mdata, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "\t")
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return bytes.NewReader(mdata), nil
    }

    rmData, err := Marshal(prayerData)
    pRmData, err := Marshal(pMonthPData)
    nRmData, err := Marshal(nMonthPData)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Save prayer data into s3
    g := new(errgroup.Group)

    s3Upload := func(rawData *io.ReadSeeker, input *LookupInput) func() error {
        return func() error {
            s3Client := s3manager.NewUploaderWithClient(awsservices.NewS3Service())
            _, err = s3Client.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
                Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
                Key: aws.String(
                    fmt.Sprintf(
                        "%s/%d/%d/%d",
                        input.Country,
                        input.ZipCode,
                        input.custTime.Year(),
                        int(input.custTime.Month()))),
                Body: *rawData,
            })
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    g.Go(s3Upload(&pRmData, pMonthLookupInput))
    g.Go(s3Upload(&rmData, input))
    g.Go(s3Upload(&nRmData, nMonthLookupInput))

    if err := g.Wait(); err == nil {

        mPrayer.PreviousMonthData = pMonthPData
        mPrayer.CurrentMonthData = prayerData
        mPrayer.NextMonthData = nMonthPData

        return mPrayer, nil
    }

    return nil, err

}
```

Here is my test file.

```golang
func TestPrayer(t *testing.T) {

    p, err := NewMonthPrayer(
        &input,
        &S3Store{},
        &AladhanStore{},
    )
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error: %s", err)
    }

    data, err := p.GetMonthPrayers()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error: %s", err)
    }
    t.Logf("Test address: %p", data)

    t.Logf("data THIS SHOULDN'T BE NIL: %v", data)
    t.Logf("ERROR: %s", err)
}
```

These are my results.  Ignore the pass result, the data is first not nil and second nil.

```golang
=== RUN   TestPrayer
loop = 0, data= *prayer.PreCurrNextMonthPrayer <nil>
attempting to retrieve prayer data from s3
    err= <nil>
    monthlyData= 0xc000131180 &{<nil> 0xc0002612f0 0xc00051e780 0xc00011cea0 []}
loop-return: err == nil 
return monthlyData address & value = 0xc000131180 &{<nil> 0xc0002612f0 0xc00051e780 0xc00011cea0 []}
post-loop:
    monthlyData= 0x0 <nil>
return monthlyData address & value = 0x0 <nil>
    prayer_test.go:53: Test address: 0x0
    prayer_test.go:55: data THIS SHOULDN'T BE NIL: <nil>
    prayer_test.go:56: ERROR: %!s(<nil>)
--- PASS: TestPrayer (0.32s)
PASS
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. Also: Please come up with a _minimal_ example showing your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I'm seeing multiple returns for one function call when I shouldn't have been.  I've fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate was due to the GetMonthPrayer call from NewMonthPrayer, which shouldn't have been the case to begin with.  It was called first but returned second, thus overwriting the existing data.

```golang
func NewMonthPrayer(input *LookupInput, prayers ...MonthPrayerIface) (*PreCurrNextMonthPrayer, error) {
    var err error
    t := &PreCurrNextMonthPrayer{
        custData: input,
        prayers:  prayers,
    }
    t, err = t.GetMonthPrayers()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return t, nil
}
```

I removed the NewMonthPrayer entirely as it was unnecessary, I also removed the function call in the process, thus fixing the initial problem.

```golang
// NewPrayer instantiates a prayer type object with the required input
func NewPrayer(input *LookupInput, prayers ...MonthPrayerIface) *Prayer {
    return &Prayer{
        custData: input,
        prayers:  prayers,
    }
}
```